# How does one add a product-item to a shopping-cart and how would one remove it from there while always (re)calculating the cart items' total price?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, dom-events, state-management, event-delegation

The following array features objects which are the product items. Clicking at the `Add to cart` button should render the related item into a table presentation via the `mytable` function as shown further below.

```
var product = [
  {"name":"jeans","image":"pics/jeans3.jpg","price":500},
  {"name":"hoodie","image":"pics/hoodie.jpg","price":700},
  {"name":"shirt","image":"pics/shirt.jpg","price":450},
  {"name":"sweter","image":"pics/sweter.jpg","price":1100},
  {"name":"trouser","image":"pics/trouser.jpg","price":600},
  {"name":"tshirt","image":"pics/tshirt.jpg","price":250}
];
```

Here is the loop which is supposed to create the product overview (event handling inclusive) from the above provided data.

```
var head = "<div id='main'>";

for (var i in product) {
  head += "<div class='pro'>";
  head += "<h1>" + product[i].name + "</h1>";
  head += "<img src=" + product[i].image + ">";
  head += "<p>" + product[i].price + "</p>";
  head += "<button onclick='mytable(i)'>Add to cart</button>"
  head += "</div>";
}
```

And here is the rest of the above code which is expected to write the product overview to the document. There is also the above mentioned `mytable` function which is supposed to create an items shopping cart presentation (event handling inclusive).

```
head += "</div>";
head += "<div id='cart'> </div>"
document.write(head);

function mytable(i) {
     document.getElementById('cart').innerHTML = "<table border='1'> <tr><th>Product name</th>  <th>Quantity</th>  <th>Price</th> <th>image</th><th><button>Remove Items</button></th></tr></table>";
}
```

Additionally I want to handle the removal of a cart item. For both cases adding and removing items to/from the cart I want to calculate the total price of all cart items.

How could one achieve this?

Comment: Hi ! So far so good :) Please provide us your attempts in javascript.

Comment: What is 'cart'? Your question is not clear.

Comment: like in shopping website there is a " button add to cart " when we click on that the data will be automatically added to the cart - @wimanicesir

Comment: I know the functionality of a cart. I mean what is cart in your project? Do you want to save it in localstorage? Do you want to show it HTML? What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: i want to show it in html ,as i click the add to cart button nothing is executed @Wimanicesir

Comment: Most probably the user is looking for something similar to ... [*"How does one establish state-management in between a list of data-items and their element-node representatives in case of removing an item on 'click'?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404034/how-does-one-establish-state-management-in-between-a-list-of-data-items-and-thei)

Comment: Maybe the most important thing was to provide with the initial data for each product a product id `pid` in order to identify rendered shopping items (main product view or cart view) and the related model data (here so far the OP's very basic product list). This ID also is vital in order to keep the client-side shopping-representation synchronized with the server-state.

Comment: The OP also does not want to use `<table/>` in order to present a shopping cart. For both different presentations of one and the same product, a list item ... `<li/>` ... is perfectly suited. Thus the product and the cart view should be rendered each into an un/ordered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techniques being used ...

Web Api

- [`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`<node>.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)
- [`<node>.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [`<element>.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)
- [`<element>.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)
- [`<element>.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`<element>.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and
- [`<htmlElement>.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
- [`<eventTarget>.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Event delegation

- [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)
- [MDN :: Introduction to events :: Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

Syntax

- [Destructuring assignment :: object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)
- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

[Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

- [Optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

JavaScript Api / Methods of [Standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const productList = [
  { pid: "abcd-0987-WXYZ", name: "jeans", price: 500, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/blue-denim-picture-id501250332" },
  { pid: "efgh-1234-QRST", name: "hoodie", price: 700, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/faceless-man-in-hoodie-standing-isolated-on-black-picture-id916306960" },
  { pid: "ijkl-6543-MNOP", name: "shirt", price: 450, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/men-shirt-for-clothing-isolated-on-white-background-picture-id641319368" },
  { pid: "mnop-5678-IJKL", name: "sweater", price: 1100, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/minimalistic-rustic-composition-with-stacked-vintage-knitted-easy-picture-id1049751604" },
  { pid: "qrst-2109-EFGH", name: "trouser", price: 600, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/pants-picture-id168790494" },
  { pid: "wxyz-9012-ABCD", name: "tshirt", price: 250, image: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/close-up-of-colorful-tshirts-on-hangers-apparel-background-picture-id1170635789" },
];

function createElementFromMarkup(html) {
  const renderBox = document.createElement('div');
  renderBox.innerHTML = html;
  return renderBox.firstElementChild;
}

function createItemMainView(data) {
  return createElementFromMarkup(`
    <li data-pid="${ data.pid }">
      <h3>${ data.name }</h3>
      <img src="${ data.image }"/>
      <dl><dt>Price</dt><dd>${ data.price }</dd></dl>
      <button data-add-pid="${ data.pid }" data-text="Add to cart">Add to cart</button>
    </li>
  `);
}
function createItemCartView(data) {
  return createElementFromMarkup(`
    <li data-pid="${ data.pid }">
      <h3>${ data.name }</h3>
      <dl><dt>Price</dt><dd>${ data.price }</dd></dl>
      <button data-remove-pid="${ data.pid }">Remove</button>
    </li>
  `);
}

function createShoppingItem(data) {
  return {
    data,
    view: {
      main: createItemMainView(data),
      cart: createItemCartView(data),
    },
    checkout: {
      isInCart: false,
      orderCount: 0,
    },
  };
}

function scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(elmNode) {
  if (elmNode) {
    const whichScrollIntoView = elmNode.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded
      ? 'scrollIntoViewIfNeeded'
      : 'scrollIntoView';
    elmNode[whichScrollIntoView]();
  }
}

function updateShoppingCartTotal(elmCartTotal, shoppingState) {
  const total = Object
    .values(shoppingState)
    .reduce((sum, item) =>
      (sum + ((item.data.price ?? 0) * (item.checkout.orderCount ?? 0))), 0
    );
  elmCartTotal.textContent = (total === 0) ? '' : total;
}

function updateCartItemPriceView(elmPrice, price, orderCount) {
  elmPrice.textContent = (orderCount >= 2)
    ? `${ price } x ${ orderCount }`
    : price;
}
function updateAddButtonItemCount(elmButton, orderCount) {
  const { text: buttonText } = elmButton.dataset;

  elmButton.textContent = (orderCount >= 1)
    ? `${ buttonText } (${ orderCount })`
    : buttonText;
}

function updateOrderCounts(pid, context) {
  const {
    target: { elmMainOverview, elmCartOverview, elmCartTotal },
    state: shoppingState,
  } = context;

  const shoppingItem = shoppingState[pid];
  const orderCount = shoppingItem?.checkout?.orderCount ?? 0;

  const elmButton = elmMainOverview
    .querySelector(`[data-add-pid="${ pid }"]`);
  const elmPrice = (orderCount >= 1) && elmCartOverview
    .querySelector(`[data-pid="${ pid }"] dd`);

  if (elmButton) {
    updateAddButtonItemCount(elmButton, orderCount);
  }
  if (elmPrice) {
    updateCartItemPriceView(elmPrice, shoppingItem?.data?.price, orderCount);
  }
  updateShoppingCartTotal(elmCartTotal, shoppingState);
}

function handleAddToCartWithBoundTargetAndState(evt) {
  const target = evt.target.closest('[data-add-pid]');
  if (target) {

    const { addPid: pid } = target.dataset;
    const {
      target: { elmCartOverview },
      state: shoppingState,
    } = this;

    const item = shoppingState[pid];
    if (item) {
      if (item.checkout.isInCart === false) {

        elmCartOverview.appendChild(item.view.cart.cloneNode(true));

        item.checkout.isInCart = true;
      }
      item.checkout.orderCount += 1;

      scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(
        elmCartOverview.querySelector(`[data-pid="${ pid }"]`)
      );
      updateOrderCounts(pid, this);
    }
    // console.log('Add To Cart :: pid ...', pid);
  }
  console.log('Add To Cart :: evt.target ...', evt.target);
}
function handleRemoveFromCartWithBoundTargetAndState(evt) {
  const target = evt.target.closest('[data-remove-pid]');
  if (target) {

    const { removePid: pid } = target.dataset;
    const {
      target: { elmMainOverview, elmCartOverview },
      state: shoppingState,
    } = this;

    const item = shoppingState[pid];
    if (item) {

      const selector = `[data-pid="${ pid }"]`;

      scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(elmMainOverview.querySelector(selector));
      elmCartOverview.querySelector(selector)?.remove();

      elmMainOverview
        .querySelector(`[data-add-pid="${ pid }"]`).focus?.();

      item.checkout.isInCart = false;
      item.checkout.orderCount = 0;

      updateOrderCounts(pid, this);
    }
    // console.log('Remove From Cart :: pid ...', pid);
  }
  console.log('Remove From Cart :: evt.target ...', evt.target);
}

function main() {
  const shoppingState = productList
    .map(createShoppingItem)
    .reduce((state, item) =>
      Object.assign(state, { [item.data.pid]: item }),
      Object.create(null)
    );
  console.log({ shoppingState })

  const elmMainOverview = document
    .querySelector('[data-product-overview]');
  const elmShoppingCart = document
    .querySelector('[data-shopping-cart]');

  const elmCartOverview = elmShoppingCart
    ?.querySelector('[data-cart-overview]');
  const elmCartTotal = elmShoppingCart
    ?.querySelector('[data-cart-total]');

  const handlerContext = {
    target: {
      elmMainOverview,
      elmCartOverview,
      elmCartTotal,
    },
    state: shoppingState,
  };
  elmMainOverview.addEventListener('click',
    handleAddToCartWithBoundTargetAndState.bind(handlerContext)
  );
  elmCartOverview.addEventListener('click',
    handleRemoveFromCartWithBoundTargetAndState.bind(handlerContext)
  );
  // initially render product list from shopping state.
  Object
    .values(shoppingState)
    .forEach(item =>
      elmMainOverview.appendChild(item.view.main.cloneNode(true))
    );
}
main();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
h3, dl, button {
  font-size: 12px;
}
img {
  max-height: 54px;
  max-width: 72px;
}
dl::after {
  clear: left;
}
dl dt {
  float: left;
}
dl dd::before {
  content: ': ';
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:target, button:focus, button:focus-within {
  outline: 1px solid #06f;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 25%;
}
#mini-cart {
  position: fixed;
  right: 60%;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 14%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#mini-cart button {
  position: unset;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%!important;
  width: 60%;
  top: 0;
  left: auto!important;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul data-product-overview>
  </ul>
</main>

<section id="mini-cart" data-shopping-cart>
  <a href="#mini-cart">
    Mini Cart
    <output data-cart-total></output>
  </a>
  <ul data-cart-overview>
  </ul>
</section>
```